# Example models with texture coordinates?

Tags: graphics, model, 3d, textures, parameterization

I'm writing a small OpenGL demo and I would really like to show some example models with textures. The trouble is I have a really tough time finding such models.

There are tons of repositories of 3D models in various formats but it seems that only a small fraction of them have texture coordinates. I'm looking for find some well known stuff like the stanford bunny or the teapot, with texture coordinates.

Anybody know where I can find these?

Answer (score 3):

[GLUT](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) has a function for generating the teapot model with texture coordinates:

[void glutSolidTeapot(GLdouble size);](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node89.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use any DCC app ( e.g. the free, and only slightly annoying [Blender](http://www.blender.org) ) to create UV coordinates for a model, assuming it reads/writes the formats you're interested in.